# Python - Regex Sub() Pattern with Letters, Special Character, Spaces

Tags: python, arrays, regex

I'm currently working on a project in which I have an array which populates names as 'Brandon Crawford (L) SS' and 'B Crawford (L) SS'

My goal: eliminate all instances like 'B Crawford (L) SS' -- i.e. keep the full first name, eliminate the short name.

I'm trying to use this script:

```
pattern = '^[A-Z] \S'
replacement = ""
no_short_name = [re.sub(pattern,replacement,player.strip()) for player in full_batters_and_pos]

print(no_short_name)
```

However, when this prints, here's what I get for an outcome: 'rawford (L) SS'

Any idea what I'm missing in order to fully eliminate these instances in my array?

Comment: Welcome to SO! In the interests of a [mcve], could you show a relevant sample of `full_batters_and_pos` and the desired output after the operation? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to filter out the items that do not match your regex:

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'^[A-Z] \S')
full_batters_and_pos = ['Brandon Crawford (L) SS', 'B Crawford (L) SS']
no_short_name = list(filter(lambda player: not pattern.search(player), full_batters_and_pos))
print(no_short_name)
# => ['Brandon Crawford (L) SS']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7NLcTR).

Filtering is performed with `filter(lambda player: not pattern.search(player), full_batters_and_pos)`: each `full_batters_and_pos` item is tested against the compiled regex `pattern`, and if it does not match, it is discarded.